# Pandas: Create 1 function to read json then create another function to create dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I would like to create a function to get data from an API, then create another function to create and clean the respective dataframe for use.

The first set of def looks like below and it works fine:

```
def get_data():

    print('start download the 1st set')
    confirm_details = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D').content
    print('complete download the 1st set')

    print('start download the 2nd set')
    latest_situ = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Flatest_situation_of_reported_cases_covid_19_eng.csv%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D').content
    print('complete download the 2nd set')

    print('start download the final set')
    residential = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fbuilding_list_eng.csv%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D').content
    print('complete download the final set')

get_data()
```

The 2nd def is as below but it said that throw me an error that "NameError: name 'confirm_details' is not defined:

```
def clean_confirm_df():
    confirm_df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(confirm_details.decode('utf-8')))
    confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_" )
    confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.replace('/', "_")
    confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.replace("*", "")
    confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.strip()
    confirm_df['Report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(confirm_df['Report_date'], dayfirst=True)
    confirm_df.rename(columns = {'Confirmed_probable': 'Confirmed'}, inplace = True)
    confirm_df = confirm_df.drop(['Name_of_hospital_admitted', 'Date_of_onset'], axis = 1)
    confirm_df['HK_Non-HK_resident'] = confirm_df['HK_Non-HK_resident'].str.upper()
    confirm_df.head()
    
clean_confirm_df()
```

I look at the 1st def and i see "confirm_details" is defined. I tried and the codes to create the respective df works (confirm_df, latest_situ_df, and residential_df) works fine when it runs individually.

I'm self-learning python and pandas, appreciate for any advises how i should change my code to make it works.

thanks.

Comment: it's all about scope,  those variables are defined in scope `get_data()` not globals.  You note functions,  but you have not defined functions,  there don't return anything.  I'd suggest a `dict` of references to JSON is returned from `get_data()` and passed as an argument to `clean_df()`.  It's worth doing a bit more online learning of basics of programming in python

Comment: thanks @RobRaymond it works. Yes I agree to your advises that l should do more online learnings. Sometimes it just difficult to get things round my head after i watch some demonstrations on youtube. I do not understand you comment that "I note function, but i do not defined function". I thought when i use def the function is defined. thanks for your helps and have a good day

Comment: it's a bit old school and fact I have worked with many programming languages.  I like the definition that a function returns something.  A subroutine just does something but does not return a anything.  However I do think it's useful to know these concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment - structure your code so you know scope of variables.  You have assumed everything is global which would be a very bad thing...

```
def get_data():
    ret = {}

    print('start download the 1st set')
    ret["confirm_details"] = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D').content
    print('complete download the 1st set')

    print('start download the 2nd set')
    ret["latest_situ"] = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Flatest_situation_of_reported_cases_covid_19_eng.csv%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D').content
    print('complete download the 2nd set')

    print('start download the final set')
    ret["residential"] = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fbuilding_list_eng.csv%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D').content
    print('complete download the final set')

    return ret

def clean_confirm_df(data):
    confirm_df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(data["confirm_details"].decode('utf-8')))
    confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_" )
    confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.replace('/', "_")
    confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.replace("*", "")
    confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.strip()
    confirm_df['Report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(confirm_df['Report_date'], dayfirst=True)
    confirm_df.rename(columns = {'Confirmed_probable': 'Confirmed'}, inplace = True)
    confirm_df = confirm_df.drop(['Name_of_hospital_admitted', 'Date_of_onset'], axis = 1)
    confirm_df['HK_Non-HK_resident'] = confirm_df['HK_Non-HK_resident'].str.upper()
    return confirm_df

mydata = get_data()
df = clean_confirm_df(mydata)
print(df.head().to_markdown())
```

```
start download the 1st set
complete download the 1st set
start download the 2nd set
complete download the 2nd set
start download the final set
complete download the final set
|    |   Case_no. | Report_date         | Gender   |   Age | Hospitalised_Discharged_Deceased   | HK_Non-HK_resident   | Case_classification   | Confirmed   |
|---:|-----------:|:--------------------|:---------|------:|:-----------------------------------|:---------------------|:----------------------|:------------|
|  0 |          1 | 2020-01-23 00:00:00 | M        |    39 | Discharged                         | NON-HK RESIDENT      | Imported case         | Confirmed   |
|  1 |          2 | 2020-01-23 00:00:00 | M        |    56 | Discharged                         | HK RESIDENT          | Imported case         | Confirmed   |
|  2 |          3 | 2020-01-24 00:00:00 | F        |    62 | Discharged                         | NON-HK RESIDENT      | Imported case         | Confirmed   |
|  3 |          4 | 2020-01-24 00:00:00 | F        |    62 | Discharged                         | NON-HK RESIDENT      | Imported case         | Confirmed   |
|  4 |          5 | 2020-01-24 00:00:00 | M        |    63 | Discharged                         | NON-HK RESIDENT      | Imported case         | Confirmed   |
```